# laravel eloquent nested SELECT statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel with Eloquent with MySQL.
I have three tables `POSTS`, `USERS` and `COMMENTS`. My `POST` and `COMMENT` are in one-to-many relation thus with the following code I get the list of Comments for particular `POST` id

```
$post =  Post::where('id', $id)->get();
$comment = Post::find($id)->comment()->paginate(10);       
return view('posts\single', ['post' => $post, 'comments' => $comment]);
```

Now I want to get the Details of each user from the `USER` table. I don't want to use the `foreach()` and then get details of every single `ID`. Is there any method by which I can get all the Comments (from `COMMENTS` table) including user details (from `USER` table) at a single call.

Comment: Using `JOIN`? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: You have to use eloquent relationships..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first need to create one to many relationship in USERS to COMMENTS (user have many comments).

and then you already have relation **post have many comments** relationship.

so, let's use Nested Eager Loading

```
$post =  Post::where('id', $id)->with('comments.user')->get();
return view('posts\single', ['post' => $post]);
```

now in your blade files....

- `$post->comments` will give you all comments for particular post.
- `$post->comments->user` will give you user who made a comment.

Comment: Well Explained! Thanks a lot Maulik. Worked Like charm

Comment: welcome :) you should mark it as answered by clicking tick button under down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Try the following:

```
$comment = Comment::where('post_id', $post->id)->with('user')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: That, unfortunately, is returning NULL at key user as "user"=>NULL

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this -

```
User::join('posts','posts.created_by','=','users.id')
      ->with('comment')
      ->where('posts.id' ,'=' ,$id)
      ->paginate(10);
```

Hope this will helpful for you.